# Custom time range JQuery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I use resource view with Fullcalendar plugin. Hours are displayed horizontally. Everything is working well except I would like to have custom time interval. I would like to have 24h calendar with day starting with 9.30am and finishing with 9.30am, I already saw 'mintime' and 'maxtime in documentation (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/minTime/) but If I try

```
minTime: '9:30',
maxTime: 9:30',
```

it doesn’t work. I even thought about using 2 calendars on the same page with one: 9.30am > 9.30pm and the other 9.30pm > 9.30 am but I would better have 24h calendar…

Anybody can help me?

[24H calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEHTw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i don't think this is possible.

Any view (agenda / basic) is based on specific days, so starttime is 0:00, endtime 23:59 the day you've choosen to be displayed.

minTime/maxTime allows you to filter a range out of the day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same.
This is what I'm working on, maybe it will help someone, or someone will help me find the solution.

I want my days to start at 7am and to stop as 7am the day after.
I "moved" all the events using another timezone (I still have to handle the summer/winter times) and I will use jQuery in order to change the "times" displayed in the left column.

Is it the fix you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I needed this functionality myself so I implemented a dayBreakTime option in my fork: https://github.com/matiaslarsson/fullcalendar

This will allow you to select at what time the calendar columns will break for a new day. Just add the option dayBreakTime: "09:30" to make the day columns span from 09:30 to 09:30 the next day, like this;

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },
   defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
   dayBreakTime: "09:30",
   ...
});
```

Please check the documentation and star the issue at https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2541 if you'd like the functionality in the main FullCalendar branch.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is the essential part of the answer: "Just add the option dayBreakTime: "09:30" to make the day columns span from 09:30 to 09:30 the next day."

But it requires a forked version of fullcalendar. Do you want me to add the code deltas as well?

Comment: Sorry that's a canned comment from the review system. If you could flesh out your answer a bit more, perhaps include a code snippet, it will probably be fine. The rule of thumb is usually "will this answer still be an answer if the links go down?"